# Dead-ish Laptop, What's next?

Tags: laptop, cooling

**UPDATE 2:**

Strange... I left it off for a few days and turned it upside down overnight. The lines disappeared... (Loose gfx card making sparking noises and lines? I don't know. Still, HP refused to stand behind its product. Time to call the BBB?

**UPDATE:**

HP's case manager decided that the best he can do is give me $100 off th repair service. Down to $298.00. Wow. what a discount.

I'm sorry. Folks - keep away from HP lappies - they overheat.

**A Little Background Information**

I have an HP dv2610 Laptop and it's making occasional popping noises while running and a few days ago, it started making a fizzling noise too, like it was going to blow up. (It sounded like popcorn, then  like a large fire in an outdoor grill. I turned it off and I consider it officially unusable  - dead, that is. I can't uses it without fear of it blowing up.

The warranty expired in November of 2008. It has had overheating problems in the past which have affected the Graphics Performance. I am certain that this was caused by the poor ventilation - probably due to HP's design of the machine.

**The question:**

Is there some way to convince HP to replace/repair it for free, because they designed the laptop with their typical "HP Compactness" which most probably caused the damage? 
Alternatively, I could buy a new one with money I don't have - not really an option.

**Edit:**

I chatted with HP. At first it was the usual, *no it's not under warranty... etc.* Then, i asked to speak with supervisor. In short I go assigned a case manager. I'm awaiting a phone call. The said phone call is supposed to be in the next 24-48 hours.

**@Mike:**

I thought about the speakers - not the heat paste. I don't want to open it at this point. My last few experiences opening up (HP) machines have not been fun. There are too many screws in too many places. I'm waiting for them to decide if they are going to help me. If yes, they have retained me as a customer. If not, then I may open it, salvage the working parts - sell em and put it towards an Acer, Dell, Lenovo or Toshiba. (alphabetically listed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe HP will honor a warranty that expired more than a year ago.

Your cheapest option is probably to take it to a qualified repairman to see what the problem is.

Comment: The thing is - I'm pretty qualified myself. (Excuse my humility here...) I fix em for neighbors and friends. I have opened it once before. HP just has a history of heat issues. I just didn't realize how bad t was - this is my first HP lappie.

Comment: I never buy HP. But being qualified, isn't anything visibly wrong?

Comment: try to re apply the heat sink paste and add a dab to your gpu while your at it..

Comment: mike - add that as an answer, not a comment ;)

Comment: harry - There is no external visible damage, and when I opened it, I had no time then to remove the mobo from the casing completely, i could've missed something entirely. I'll bet that either mike is right, the heat paste is gone, or something got *REALLY* hot despite the paste being there.

Comment: Heat damage is possible, although in my experience most computers will shutdown before, rather then make frying-pan noises. It might be the power supply that died or some other short-circuit. Again: only a qualified repairman with the right tools can find what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

New laptops are remarkably cheap now.  Sorry, I know that isn't what you wanted to hear.

Comment: nope. It wasn't. Plus one, cute answer. HP Suppport is "escalating" my "case" now...

Comment: @Moshe so what happened? My hp lap just went kaput a few hours ago, no reason, just like that. Even the charging notification light doesnt show.

Comment: Haven't used that laptop in years - but I'd suggest opening it and cleaning it out. Maybe have a professional do it if you're uncomfortable.